# relative references in .net

Tags: .net, reference

I browse to a a dll and add it as a reference.  The problem is the reference absolute path is being stored.  How do I change this to be a relative reference instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/msbuild/thread/c2d3b9c3-edc6-4564-8072-44fb26b9fb83) might be helpful to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think VS adds relative path to the referenced assemblies.

You can always **edit .csproj** file as it's **regular xml** file:

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="XXX, Version=2.7.3424.39182,...">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\Lib\XXX.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```